# Apache conf Listen not allowed here

Tags: apache-2.4

I try Apache 2.4 conf:

```
  Listen 443

  #if SECOND_HOST_PORT is defined and is not 443 listen on it 

  <IfDefine !SECOND_HOST_PORT>
    Define SECOND_HOST_PORT 443
  </IfDefine>

  <If "'${SECOND_HOST_PORT}' != '443'">
    Listen ${SECOND_HOST_PORT}
  </If>
```

But I get:

> Listen not allowed here

In the line before last

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Listen` in a place where it is not allowed.

According to [the `Listen` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) the only allowed context is `server config`.

According to [the `context` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) this means that it is NOT allowed in a `<VirtualHost>` directive, a `<Directory>` directive, or in a .htaccess file.

Further, the description of a `<Directory>` context indicates that the `<Location>`, `<Files>`, `<If>`, and `<Proxy>` directives are handled like `<Directory>`.

So you can't use it inside an `<If>`.

---

It works inside the `<IfDefine>` directive.

```
Define SECOND_HOST_PORT 4711

<IfDefine SECOND_HOST_PORT>
  Listen ${SECOND_HOST_PORT}
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to achieve what I want ? listen conditionally ?

Comment: It should work inside the `<IfDefine>` directive.